# ES2015: Call Inner method from overwrited class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, ecmascript-6

I am learning ES6 classes and object. In order to that I'm making a sample app, and I found this issue:

I have this MainClass:

```
class App {
    boot() {
        console.log('app booted')
    }
}
```

Then I have another Class, that extends from the first one:

```
class someClass extends App {
    boot() {
        this.update()
    }
    update() {
        console.log('update Method!')
    }
}
```

From `someClass` I'm overwriting the boot method. This works fine, since it's trying to call `update` mothod.

But it's returning `update` method as `undefined`.

I get that, `this` in this case is the `App` class, so `update` is undefined inside `App`.

Is there a way to call the `update` method from the `boot` method in `someClass` class?

Comment: *"I get that, this in this case is the App class, so update is undefined inside App."* No, that's incorrect. What `this` refers to depends on how you call `boot`. Maybe you are passing `boot` as a callback somewhere. In that case, have a look at [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196). If that's not the case, please show us how you call it.

Comment: I second Felix. Please add how you call, what return values you expect and what logging you expect and what you actually get in both terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Instantiate a new object and then call `boot()` on that object. For example like so:

```
class App {
    boot() {
        console.log('app booted')
    }
}

class someClass extends App {
    boot() {
        this.update()
    }
    update() {
        console.log('update Method!')
    }
}

const test = new someClass();
test.boot(); // update Method!
```

You can test your code [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=class%20App%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20boot()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('app%20booted')%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20someClass%20extends%20App%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20boot()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.update()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20update()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('update%20Method!')%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20new%20someClass()%3B%0Atest.boot()%3B).